# React Native Grid view to show comparsion table

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

Using react native how can I build a comparison table, which looks like
https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/smart-phone-comparison-table.png

I also want to have a section header if possible. Eg The Price is not in its own column but is similar to a table section header in iOS
A List view will give me one column but I want multiple columns

Thanks

EDIT:
The below code works but the problem is that if I scroll horizontal then only one list view will scroll. I want both of them to scroll. (I am basically trying to make rows and columns like excel, in my case the data may be large (30 rows and 5-8 columns) and I don't want to hardcode it.)

```
 render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView> 
      <ListView horizontal
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />

         <ListView horizontal
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />

      </ScrollView>
    )
```

In the below image I want both the list views to be scrolled when the 2nd one is scrolled but as seen in the image only the 2nd ListView is scrolling and not the first one... 
[image]

Comment: There is no out-of-box Table component in react-native. but it's not difficult to draw it using ListView, and render each row with `style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}`

Comment: @Takahiro Thanks for the comment. I don't want to hardcode the values. The data will be comming from the server. I tried the updated code above,  but the problem is that if I scroll horizontal then only one list view will scroll. I want both of them to scroll.

Comment: Why do you need multiple ListViews? I thought you only need one (for a table). And offcourse you don't need to hardcode the values if you're using ListViewDataSource. everything you need to do is to transform your DataSource, and render each row as a list of cells, and use flex layout to align them.

Comment: Yes, Suppose I have a scroll view and that has 2 list views inside them which are horizontal. Now If I scroll the horizontal listview1 I want to listView2 also to be scrolled. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm afraid not, currently nested scrollview is a outstanding issue in react-native. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8024

Answer (score 1):

This can be very Easily achieved using flex-box styling. If you are newbie in to React-native. Listview is kinda of daunting  at first look( Datasource, what is it with clone with rows {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})??). To keep it simple and better understand Flex-box this should do your job. But ListView is more recommended.
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,View, ListView, StyleSheet,Text } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>

          <View style={styles.Row}>
              <View style={styles.Box1}>
                  <Text>Box 1</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.Box2}>
                  <Text>Box 2</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.Box1}>
                  <Text>Box 3</Text>
              </View>
              {/*
                <View....
                The more Views you add here the more horizontal Boxes you have
                */}
          </View>


          <View style={styles.Row}>
              <View style={styles.Box2}>
                  <Text>Box 1</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.Box1}>
                  <Text>Box 2</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.Box2}>
                  <Text>Box 3</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*
            <View....
            The more Views you add here the more rows  you have
            */}

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Row : {flex:1,flexDirection:'row'},
  Box1 : {flex:1,backgroundColor:'tan',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'},
  Box2 : {flex:1,backgroundColor:'coral',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'},
});

module.exports = Example
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I use the ListView to achieve this? 
As my table will be really big and the data will be fetched from the server.?

I tried the code below but if I scroll one list view the other one would not scroll horizontally which I want. (See above I updated the answer with the code)

Comment: Are you trying to implement two listviews parallelly(one on left and one on right) of which both should scroll independently.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I can think of which can make a grid. @Vkrm

Comment: In the below image I want both the list views to be scrolled when the 2nd one is scrolled but as seen in the image only the 2nd ListView is scrolling and not the first one... 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNvZz.png

Comment: Please have a look at new answer. if it does not help, please PM me here : https://www.facebook.com/belvikram

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

class MultiScroll extends Component {

  render() {
    var tableData = []
    for(i = 0; i < 90; i++){
      tableData.push(['Row '+ i + ' Item 1','Row '+ i + ' Item 2','Row '+ i + ' Item 3','Row '+ i + ' Item 4','Row '+ i + ' Item 5','Row '+ i + ' Item 6','Row '+ i + ' Item 7','Row '+ i + ' Item 8','Row '+ i + ' Item 9','Row '+ i + ' Item 10'])
    }
    return (
      <View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop:0}}>
          <ScrollView>
            <ScrollView horizontal = {true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= {false}>
                <View style={{}}>
                  {
                    tableData.map((eachRow,j) => {
                          return (
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}} key = {j}>
                                {
                                  eachRow.map((eachItem,i) => {
                                    return <View key = {i} style={{width:100,height:30,backgroundColor:(((j+i)%2)?'tan':'coral'),alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}><Text>{eachItem}</Text></View>
                                  })
                                }
                            </View>
                          );
                      })
                  }
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </ScrollView>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = MultiScroll
```

[image] 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is awesome! Just want I wanted. Thank you! :) 

One last thing, If I have say 90 rows then my vertical scroll does not work if I place the horizontal scroll view inside the      vertical one                                 <ScrollView vertical = {true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= {false} >
</ScrollView>

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still can't scroll vertically. It bounces back automatically. Is this happening for you too? @Vkrm

Comment: I dont have an issue with verticle scrolling. Probably try setting parent component which is  holding this component to flex:1.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<View>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <ScrollView horizontal ={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= {false}>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <ScrollView horizontal ={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= {false}>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:30}}><Text>Button</Text></View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
```

I'm unable to insert a Image into comment. So, adding as an answer.

Comment: This is great, Thanks but I want both the rows to scroll simultaneously. I want to build a comparison table like https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/smart-phone-comparison-table.png .  The Data will be coming from a server so I am also unaware of how many rows and columns would be there.